# Need help understanding Boost.Atomic Memory Model `memory_order_release` Example

Tags: c++, boost, atomic, memory-model

I was going over the boost Atomic documentation and I came across the following example:

```
atomic<int> a(0);

thread1:
  ... /* A */
  a.fetch_add(1, memory_order_release);

thread2:
  int tmp = a.load(memory_order_acquire);
  if (tmp == 1) 
  {
    ... /* B */
  } 
  else 
  {
    ... /* C */
  }
```

Now I am still a bit confused regarding memory_order_release and memory_order_acquire .The documentation describes them as:

**memory_order_release**

> Perform release operation. Informally speaking, prevents all preceding
>   memory operations to be reordered past this point.

**memory_order_acquire**

> Perform acquire operation. Informally speaking, prevents succeeding
>   memory operations to be reordered before this point.

Even with these examples I am still a bit confused. I would appreciate it if someone could explain what the above definitions mean and also how can A and C be in conflict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions mean that none of the memory operation in A can be reordered after the store to `a` (definition of *release* in the question). And that none of the operations in B or C can precede the load of `a` in the other thread (definition of *acquire* in the question).

Now, the example is assuming that there is no other code that operates on `a`, or at least that writes to `a`. If B is executed, it means that `a` had the value 1 when the load into `tmp` happened. For `a` to have value 1, the `fetch_add` had to be executed before (the `fetch_add` synchronizes with the `load`), which means that the code in A completed execution. If that particular code path is hit, the ordering of the operations is:

```
A
a.fetch_add(1,memory_order_release);
int tmp = a.load(memory_order_acquire);
B
```

Now the other options is that when the `load` happens the value is still 0. That implies that the first thread did not get to execute the `fetch_add`, but there is no guarantee as of where it might be executing. By the time that thread 2 executes C, A might still be executing (or it might have not even started, or it might have completed).

If both A and B access the same variable, there is no conflict, because the atomic guarantees that B can only be executed after A has already completed. On the other hand, that guarantee is not given for C, so if A and C touch the same variable and at least one of them writes to it, then there is a race condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.That explains a lot . One more question , in the start of your post you stated that `The definitions mean that none of the memory operation in A can be reordered after the store to a`. Could you explain what reordering means here what does "non of the memory operations can be reordered mean" ?

Comment: @MistyD: If the last line of A contained an update to a variable `b`, the `memory_order_release` ensures that neither the compiler nor the CPU will reorder the write to `b` to happen after the update to `a`. Without that guarantee, there could be a race condition if B accessed `b`